# Get value from dynamically created controls in updatepanel

Tags: c#, vb.net, dynamic, updatepanel

In a `asp:DataList` I have different rows with some text and each with one button. On this button the OnClientClick opens a jquery dialog, and the onclick calls the backend and populates an updatepanel inside the shown dialog.

The backend gives me values like "AV" "TEXT", which means, that I should populate a Textbox and when returning the values the identifier of this is known as "AV". There can be an infinite number of controls, and I add them to a (dynamically created) Table.

This works fine. But in the updatepanel I have a button which should save these values and IDs, but I cannot find them! I've tried adding the Table to `Session` which let me find the controls, but the values is not there. If not added to session, the controls isn't there.

```
<div id="dialog-confirm" style="display: none;">
<div id='dialog'>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upEditUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlVars" runat="server">
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:Button ID="btnOK" runat="server" Text="OK" OnClientClick="StartLoader();" OnClick="btnOK_Click" align="center" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnOK" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

The controls is added as follows:

```
Dim pnlVars As Panel = upEditUpdatePanel.FindControl("pnlVars")
...
controls = GetControls()
Swtich controls.type
Case "TEXT"
Dim txtVar As New TextBox
txtVar.ID = "AV"
tblCellVal.Controls.Add(txtVar)
tblRow.Cells.Add(tblCellVal)
tblVars.Controls.Add(tblRow)
pnlVars.Controls.Add(tblVars)
....
upEditUpdatePanel.Update()
```

The way I'm trying to get the values and iterate controls:

```
    Protected Sub btnOK_Click(ByVal sender As Object, _
                      ByVal e As EventArgs)
    For Each c As Control In pnlVars.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is Control Then

            If TypeOf c Is TextBox Then
                Dim ctr As TextBox = DirectCast(c, TextBox)
            End If

        End If
        If c.Controls.Count > 0 Then
            GetUserControls(c.Controls)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Accept answers in vb.net or c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn about asp.net `Page Cycle`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

To get values that has been, dynamically created you have to get them from

```
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // get values from your dynamically created elements
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've implemented this, but when I try to iterate pnlVars.Controls here it's empty.

Comment: That is - the textproperty is empty.

Comment: You should rebind it to get these values

Comment: How should I rebind? If i try to FindControl("AV") it's empty. If I save controls in session and get in Init or PreRender the Textproperty is empty.

Comment: Although a bit - for me anyways - vague answer, this guided me the right direction and found help elsewhere, and got the solution. thanks